# print array in transpose format using jquery

Tags: javascript

I am little bit stuck in the below logic.

```js
var t = new Array(),
  i = 1;
for (var s = 0; s < 7; s++) {
  t[s] = [];
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    t[s][j] = i;
    if (i === 6) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
console.log(t);
```

In my tried logic i am getting array like below

```
0: [1,2,3,4,5,6,1]
1: [2,3,4,5,6,1,2]
2: [3,4,5,6,1,2,3]
3: [4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
4: [5,6,1,2,3,4,5]
5: [6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
6: [1,2,3,4,5,6,1]
```

But I want output

```
0: [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]
1: [2,3,4,5,6,0,1]
2: [3,4,5,6,0,1,2]
3: [4,5,6,0,1,2,3]
4: [5,6,0,1,2,3,4]
5: [6,0,1,2,3,4,5]
6: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Looking for help.

Comment: this is not php, can you please remove all your dollars, they lessen visibility and finally this is not jquery dependant.

Comment: @user753642 there is a no input array. it will create an array. and `$` sign removed. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by rotating array.

```js
let len = 7;
let a = Array.from(Array(len).keys());

let ans = [];

for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
 a = a.slice(1,a.length).concat(a.slice(0,1));
 ans.push(a);
}

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it in a different approach - You are building a two dimensional array that each new element (or row) is shifted or incremented by one (6 is the max value)
So increment each value by one and store the result.

```js
    $column = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0];
    $max    = 6; 
    $rows   = 7;
    $result = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
      $result[$i] = [...$column];
      for ($j = 0; $j < $column.length; $j++) {
        if ($column[$j] == $max) $column[$j] = 0;
        else $column[$j]++;
      }
    }

    console.log($result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I really appreciated. it is also working fine.  but I don't want to declare predefined column values. like this `$column = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0];`

Answer (score 1):

reason of your bug

when doing so for the case `i == 6`

```
i = 0
i++
```

You are incrementing i twice... (from 6 to 1 instead of from 6 to 0)

You can:

```
if (i === 6) {
  i = 0;
} else {
  i++;
}
```

or more elegantly

```
i = (i + 1) % 7
```

Now you want i to be valid before assignment

`t[s][j] = i` will be not good if `i == 7`

so modulo it before

```
t[s][j] = i % 7
i++
```

```js
let t = []
let i = 1
for (let s = 0; s < 7; s++) {
  t[s] = []
  i = s + 1 // start of your row
  for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    t[s][j] = i % 7
    ++i
  }
}

console.log(t.map(r=>r.join(',')).join('\n'))
```

---

finally you can shorten your code by using map

```js
let t = Array(7).fill(0).map( (r, i) => {
  return Array(7).fill(0).map( (c, j) => ((i + 1) + j) % 7)
})
console.log(t.map(r=>r.join(',')).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use modulo. Using `k % n` will make the number rotate to 0 with every `n`

Also, you don't need the variable `i`. You could calculate it using `s + j + 1` instead.

```js
function p(a)
{
  let str="";
  for(i of a)
  {
    for(j of i)
    {
      str += j + " ";
    }
    str += "\n";
  }
  console.log(str);
}

var t = new Array();
var arraySize = 7;
var rotateEvery = 7;
for (var s = 0; s < arraySize; s++) {
    t[s] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        t[s][j] = (s + j + 1) % rotateEvery;
    }
}
p(t);
```

Comment: nah it is a output which i want

Comment: the array is the same, I only add the function `p` to ease the demonstration